Getting Blocked Mixed content while calling non secure API from secure Angular application
I am working on an application where I want to call the nonsecure API from a secure web angular application but I am getting an error with "Blocked Mixed Content". Below is the code I am by-passing the proxy but not working for me.

proxy.conf.json

{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://10.222.244.53:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin" : true
    }
}


angular.json

Serve:{
"options": {
    "browserTarget": "atlantis:build",
    "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json",
    "ssl": false

}
}


This post might help you.

I have gone through the above link but not working for me
